# Fullcalendar options not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use FullCalendar. None of the options into the init function are working. There are no console errors, or any feedback of any kind it seems. When I try to use the "header" option, the actual header seems to just disappear!

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>VetPro Dashboard</title>

    <!-- Style Css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/fonts/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../vendor/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../vendor/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.css">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/javascripts/calendar_scheduler.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="split-background">

    <!-- Start Body -->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="vetpro-dashboard">
      <div class="container container-border">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="calendar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="exceptions">
          <div id="scheduler">
            <div id="timepicker">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Body -->

  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my Javascript:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Full calendar
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
            dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
        alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
        alert('Current view: ' + view.name);
        // change the day's background color just for fun
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });


        // Moment.js locale
        moment.locale('en', {
            calendar : {
                lastDay : '[Yesterday]',
                sameDay : '[Today]',
                nextDay : '[Tomorrow]',
                lastWeek : '[last] dddd',
                nextWeek : 'dddd',
                sameElse : 'dddd'
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

What's wrong here? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the documentation did not cover that including the "print.css" file would ruin everything else. Remove that line resolved the problem.

Comment: If you include fullcalendar.print.css, use media="print" to indicate it should only be used when printing     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../vendor/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print">

Comment: There is an **theme** option in the full calender lib. if you set it to true, then you need to use external styling like jquery ui theme.